# HIVE comparing strings in join

Tags: hive

I have keys in hive query which are strings. Joing that looks like its taking forever. Can I create an index or something instead of?

```
select
*
from e 

left join tabele a
on e.string1=a.string2
```

How can improve that that it would be faster?

Answer (score 0):

Just for performance issue ,try to make hive tables as ORC format .
Try to use Map join in query and try.
http://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/19/mapjoin-a-simple-way-to-speed-up-your-hive-queries/

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC